# Dynamic iframe contents returns source, not parsed code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

First question, so please correct me if this is in the wrong format.

I need to retrieve html for two dynamic elements from a dynamically created iframe, the below code returns "undefined". But I'm probably missing something really obvious.

```
$("#frame0").contents().find(elementID).html();
```

I am loading a same domain page into an iframe, two elements in the iframe are created from its jquery, the rest is static content in the iframe. The iframe is created and appended on a button click. The iframe in page looks and loads perfectly.

Below is the relevant code from within my button click:

```
$("#frameWrapper").append($('<iframe id="frame0" src="' + url + '"/>'));
$("#frame0").bind("load",function(){
    var html = $(this).contents().find('#content').html();
    var data = $(this).contents().find(elementID).html();
    var table = $(this).contents().find(elementID).parent().find("table").html();
    console.log(html);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(table);
});
```

**#frameWrapper** is a dynamically added container in the current page.

**#frame0** is the actual iframe.

Of the three console.logs in the above code, **html** always returns the source code which is not the same as the actual view in the iframe on the page, **data** and **table** are always undefined, they are the two dynamic elements.

If I remove .html() from the above code, then all three elements are found and returned in the console.log.

I have tried too many things to list, as many answers on here as I can find, including checking all the suggested ones while I was writing this. But some of the ideas include, using plain javascript and adding a timeout to ensure load has completed, always the same response.

EDIT: Added the basic iframe code:

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="elementID"></div>
        <table class="table"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**#elementID** and **.table** are empty in the source and are only populated via a jquery function on load.

EDIT2: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Forever_Nomad/ke0ds0f7/4/) obviously it's having issues with Cross-domain policy so it's not really a good example, but it is a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#frameWrapper").on("load", "#frame0", function () {
    var html = $(this).contents().find('#content').html();
    var data = $(this).contents().find(elementID).html();
    var table = $(this).contents().find(elementID).parent().find("table").html();
    console.log(html);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(table);
});
```

...instead of `$("#frame0").bind("load",function(){...`

This is called *delegated events* and should be used since the iframe is dynamically generated.

I don't have a working code to test for your issue, therefore the above is my guess to resolve your problem.

Comment: Wow, quick answer, thanks. I've tried making that change, including making the initial #frameWrapper a static element, but the load event doesn't get called at all and no console.logs output.

Comment: @ForeverNomad Can you create a sample code of you issue? I'll be able to better assist you

Comment: I started writing a jsfiddle, but I'm not sure how to load a same domain iframe into it, which I think is the important part.

Comment: @ForeverNomad you can load any public webpage and try to get a specific element from it. But the iframe should be dynamic

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my question, but the cross-domain policy is an issue I can't get around and doesn't really serve to show the problem directly.

Comment: @ForeverNomad Have a look at [the updated JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/ke0ds0f7/5/). It should normally work if you are loading pages from the same server. In the example it won't load due to cross domain, but should work for you :)